# Name for Variable satisfying an inequality with equality

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

In mathematics we often have statements like `a x <= b`, where `a` and `b` are constants and `x` is a variable.

Now there may be variables satisfying the inequality (that is the statement is true) as well as variables violating it (in which case it's false).

However I don't have any words in my vocabulary to express stricter statements:
Is there a word to describe that the variable `x` satisfies the *equality* `a x = b`? What about the case that `a x < b`?
I remember having read "`x` is a root of the inequality" meaning `a x = b` somewhere, but I can't remember where.

Comment: Wouldn't this sort of specialised vocabulary be more likely to be found on Math.SE?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well maybe it's known there, but it's specific to the english language. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: I've seen those Math folks on Math.SE write above-average English. They can format math better than here, as well. Further, you'd also have the opportunity to find out if there's a German phrase if there were no English equivalent.

Comment: Well then, if you all think it's better there, I won't stop you ;-) May this be migrated easily or shall I just post a new question there?

Comment: You can flag for mod attention yourself and ask for it to be migrated. Do _not_ post the same question on both sites please. For what it's worth, I think the question is fine here, I'd wait a while to see if you get a good answer and then ask for migration of you don't.

Comment: "x is a root of the inequality meaning a x = b": this doesn't make any sense; inequality != equality. In your examples the x you describe are solutions for the (in)equations. In equation solving, a solution is sometimes referred to as a root.

Answer (score 3):

The equation

> ax = b

is a special case of the inequality

> ax is less-than-or-equal-to b

(I can't achieve the correct symbol either).

If x satisfies the *equation*, it is a **root** of the equation or a **solution** of the equation. (in fact, for a linear equation as here, **the** root / solution)

If x satisfies the inequality (here extended to mean the combination of equation / inequality), it is a member of the solution set of the inequality. This will typically be an infinite set. I've never heard of a term like 'root' being used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the domain of Operations Research, the variable that you add to make an inequality an equality is a [slack variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable). I realize that you are looking for a factor to multiply rather than an augend to add, but the "slack variable" synapse fired for me.

Comment: Nope, that's not remotely what I'm looking for. I do not have factors or additional variables. It's the property of the variable I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, if an inequality is satisfied with equality, you say that the inequality is *tight*.

Comment: Interesting and certainly a step in the right direction. However I'm searching for the term describing the variable that makes the inequality tight.

Comment: I don't know if there's a name for this, because it isn't really a valid mathematical concept. There's not just one variable that makes the inequality tight … if there are four variables involved in the inequality, they ***all*** make the inequality tight together. Change any one of them, and the two sides are probably no longer equal. If there's only one variable in the inequality, then it does make sense mathematically, but I don't know a name for it.

Comment: I never required uniqueness. In fact, this would be rather odd. I also never stated that this is a one-dimensional problem. I'll rephrase the question later.

Comment: I think I now understand; you're looking for a short term for "the values of the variables that make the inequality tight". I don't know whether such a term exists.